# Navigation in listing of posts from category WP

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone help me to improve my code in category.php, I need do add a simple navigation (Older Entries) under the 3 posts. When I use `<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>`nothing appears. Here is my code

```
    <div id="category">
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 6 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="news">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a> <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with category parameter in your query but try with replace query section w

**`$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3 , 'cat' => 3)`**

```
<?php
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3 , 'cat' => 3);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
?>
<div class="news">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a> <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php }
      } else {
    // no posts found
}
```

you can try using by  **`<?php get_the_permalink(); ?>`** if it is not working